# python programming

Tags: python

: N^N

Write a function called exactly NtoN() which takes a number (integer or float) as its sole parameter and returns the value of that number raised to the power of itself.

Comment: We won't write code for you, nor do your homework...

Comment: @zawa, these people try to help you. If you can't do your homework now, you are in serious problems later in your life. So keep down your language and maybe an apology is appropriate...

Comment: Not a real question? It's not ambiguous, it's not vague, not incomplete, it's certainly not overly broad, it's not rhetorical, and it can very easily be answered in its current form. On what basis is it then closed? Too easy?

Comment: bcz some haters here just dont want to help ..if i iknew how to do it why whould i post it up

Comment: People love to help. What they don't love is questions that reek of homework with no thought or attempts put in (i.e. what did you try that didn't work?). That, and you didn't actually ask any question to begin with. You just threw a problem statement at us.

Comment: @zawa: People help if you make some effort. We don't do homework. And no one is hater, we are actually doing you real good by not answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
def NtoN(n):
  return n**n
```

Intentionally made CW